# Closing question as should be on other SE site

Tags: support

I think that [Question about C++ navigation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4413/c-code-navigation-on-os-x)  should be on Stack Exchange. So I tried to flag it as off-topic - the off-topic box only gave me the choice of meta for this - on other SE sites it would list other SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think the post is OK for the site, and it's gotten some decent answers.

In the future, you can flag a post for moderator attention and a moderator can migrate it to any SE site if it needs to be moved.

Comment: The problem becomes that the same questions will end up on multiple sites and be more difficult to find